# Unable to set td padding in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have seen a few posts about iTextSharp not supporting all of the css properties but is there a way to remove the padding in all of the table cells?

I have a basic table which is populated using the streamreader to get the html from a file. I also have a Stylesheet in which I have tried both:

```
testCss.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TD, HtmlTags.CELLPADDING, "0");
testCss.LoadStyle("td","style", "padding: 0px;");
```

but neither of which seem to have any effect on the table. Is there an easy way to remove the cell padding so that the text isn't so spaced out?

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLWorker was deprecated long ago in favor of the XmlWorker so I recommend looking into that first.

That said, if you [look at the source code for CSS resolution](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/StyleSheet.cs#l175) that the HTMLWorker eventually calls you'll see that `HtmlTags.CELLPADDING` never gets used. The `HtmlTags` class has pretty much every HTML tag and attribute (at least from the 4.0 era) but few of the attributes were actually implemented. Zero work will ever be done in `HTMLWorker` so you shouldn't expect any changes ever. Once again, check out the `XmlWorker`.

However, once you parse your HTML you should get back a collection of `IElement` objects. You can manually walk these objects looking for ones of type `PdfPTable` and then use the [code here to manually set your own padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232822/231316).