# How to set space between two cells

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, itext

In [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), how to set the space between two cells([PdfPCell](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html))

Code:

```
var doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:/Doc1.pdf", FileMode.Create));

doc.Open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell1"));
cell1.Colspan = 1;
table2.AddCell(cell1);

PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell2"));
cell2.Colspan = 1;
table2.AddCell(cell2);

doc.Add(table);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Doc1.pdf");
```

Here, two cells are created(*cell2's left border* overlapped with *cell1's border right*). But I need a little *space* between 2 cells.

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10232822/231316

Comment: I tried already. But the border overlapping is there...I achieved the goal and I posted as an answer. Please refer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved by setting `width` for the columns in the table as following.

```
table.SetWidths(new float[] { 1f, 0.1f, 1f });

PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell1"));
table.AddCell(cell1);

//dummy cell created to have an empty space with width `0.1f` which was declared //above.
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
table.AddCell(cell2);

PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell3"));
table.AddCell(cell3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Play around a bit with cellpadding. Like this:

```
var doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:/Doc1.pdf", FileMode.Create));

doc.Open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell1"));
cell1.Colspan = 1;
cell.PaddingRight = 20f; //Here you can set padding (Top, Bottom, Right, Left)
table2.AddCell(cell1);

PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell2"));
cell2.Colspan = 1;
table2.AddCell(cell2);

doc.Add(table);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Doc1.pdf");
```

Comment: No. I tried. The changes happens inside the cells. My question is between two cells, I need a space.